# Wants to create choice field dynamically i.e. current time after that + 30 min

Tags: python, django, django-models, choicefield

My code is below:

```
def datetime_result():
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    intervalTime = 30

    currenttime = t.minute

    checktm = int(currenttime) - int(intervalTime)

    if checktm < 0:
        addtime = abs(checktm)
    elif checktm > 0:
        addtime = intervalTime - checktm
    else:
        addtime = checktm

    opentime = t + datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(addtime))
    closetime = datetime.time(22, 30, 0)
    firsttime = opentime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)

    start_time = opentime.strftime('%H:%M')
    end_time = closetime.strftime('%H:%M')
    slot_time = 30

    # Start date from today to next 5 day
    start_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=0)

    days = []
    Delivery_Time_CHOICES = ""
    date = start_date
    while date <= end_date:
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M')
        end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%H:%M')
        while time <= end:
            Delivery_Time_CHOICES += ('(' + "'" + time.strftime("%I.%M%p")
                + "'" + ', ' + "'" + time.strftime("%I.%M%p") + "'" + '),')
            time += datetime.timedelta(minutes=slot_time)
        date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return '(' + Delivery_Time_CHOICES + ')'
```

This code will generate time from current time + 30 minutes on wards time. when i called this method in choice filed gives me error **"string index out of range"** and when i put printed value of this method direct in choice field variable then its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the dateutils.relativedelta module.

You can easily manipulate datetime objects, setting specific hour, minute second values, etc. Or, you can use it to change a datetime by the required hours/minutes/seconds etc.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

my_original_datetime = datetime.now()

minutes_offset = 30

opening_time = datetime.now() + relativedelta(minute=0, seconds=0, microsecond=0)
closing_time = datetime.now() + relativedelta(hour=17, minute=0, seconds=0, microsecond=0)

delivery_slot_start = opening_time
delivery_slot_end = delivery_slot_start + relativedelta(minutes=minutes_offset)

available_delivery_times = [(delivery_slot_start.strftime('%H:%M'), delivery_slot_end.strftime('%H:%M'))]

while delivery_slot_end <= closing_time:
    delivery_slot_start = delivery_slot_end
    delivery_slot_end += relativedelta(minutes=minutes_offset)
    available_delivery_times.append(
        (delivery_slot_start.strftime('%H:%M'), 
         delivery_slot_end.strftime('%H:%M'))
    )

print(tuple(available_delivery_times))
```

Comment: It's exactly same what is needed but i want output like a tuple i.e 
(('11.30am', '11.30am'), ('12.30am', '12.30am'), ('01.00pm', '01.00pm'), ('01.30pm', '01.30pm'), ('02.00pm', '02.00pm'), ('02.30pm', '02.30pm'), ('03.00pm', '03.00pm'), ('03.30pm', '03.30pm'), ('04.00pm', '04.00pm'), ('04.30pm', '04.30pm'), ('05.00pm', '05.00pm'), ('05.30pm', '05.30pm'),
('06.00pm', '06.00pm'), ('06.30pm', '06.30pm'), ('07.00pm', '07.00pm'), ('07.30pm', '07.30pm'), ('08.00pm', '08.00pm'), ('08.30pm', '08.30pm'), ('09.00pm', '09.00pm'), ('09.30pm', '09.30pm'), ('10.00pm', '10.00pm'), ('10.30pm', '10.30pm'),)